# How do I retrieve and display all children of a parent node in binary tree

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
public function get_all_downlines($id){
    $tree = array();
    $this->db->where('sponsor_id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    $children =  $query->result_array();
    foreach($children as $child){
        $tree[] = $this->get_all_downlines($child['id']) ;
    }
    return $tree;
}
```

I am using adjacency list and have columns like id, sponsor_id and position. What I am able to output with the code above is empty array. I want to be able to output the arrays in a manner that suggests hierarchy. Please I need your help good people. I have been racking my head for days now.
For a parent that has say 6 downlines, I am getting something like this below
     Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) ) [1] => Array  [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) ) )

my updated code

```
  public function get_all_downlines($id){
  $tree = array();
   $this->db->where('sponsor_id', $id);
  $query = $this->db->get('users');
  $children =  $query->result_array();
     foreach($children as $child){
        $tree[$child['id']] = $this->get_all_downlines($child['id']);
     }
     return $tree;


}
```

Comment: The codes working as expected, your not attaching the data to it, so its simply creating a tree of empty arrays.

Comment: You need to add the data to it so something like: https://3v4l.org/o3bLU, else its just like: https://3v4l.org/GQfqL

Comment: Waoh! Lawrence you are a great guy. I am now getting arrays like this Array ( [4] => Array ( [8] => Array ( [16] => Array ( ) ) [9] => Array ( ) ) [5] => Array ( [10] => Array ( ) [11] => Array ( ) ) ). see my updated code below.

Comment: But one last thing great guy. I haven't gotten to the end of my journey. I am wondering how I can use the output array to build a binary or hierarchical tree. At least represent it in a tree structure to show hierarchy like multi level marketing tree. A simple approach is what I seek. Is there a class in can feed it to to output that? What is the simplest approach to this?

Comment: Even if i can get a clue to building a directory structure that suggests hierarchy. That will be equally good

Comment: You have the tree/array, you just need to display it, im not sure why you choose to discard the data and only use the key, as your need to re-query it again to get anything useful for display.

Comment: I ran the query again to get the username. Here is what i got Array ( [alexo] => Array ( [whitegraces] => Array ( [whito] => Array ( ) ) [Nicole] => Array ( ) ) [bobo] => Array ( [hilary] => Array ( ) [gucci] => Array ( ) ) )

Comment: Any idea how can i generate it as a tree or nested directory? Stuck here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```html
public function getAllComponentTree($id =''){
  $tree = array();
  $this->db->select('id, scheme_component_name, parent_id');
  $this->db->from('mst_scheme_component');
  if(!empty($id)){
      $this->db->where('parent_id', $id);
  }else{
   $this->db->where('parent_id is NULL');
  }
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $children =  $query->result_array();

      foreach($children as $child){
       $data = $this->getAllComponentTree($child['id']);
       if(!empty($data)){
          $tree[] = $child;
          $tree[$child['id']] = $this->getAllComponentTree($child['id']);
       }else{
        $tree[] = $child;
       }
      }
      return $tree;
 }
```

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [scheme_component_name] => test Data
            [parent_id] => 
        )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 59
                [scheme_component_name] =>test Data
                [parent_id] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 60
                [scheme_component_name] => test Data
                [parent_id] => 1
            )

        [60] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 62
                        [scheme_component_name] => test Data
                        [parent_id] => 60
                    )

                [62] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 63
                                [scheme_component_name] => test Data
                                [parent_id] => 62
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 61
                [scheme_component_name] => test Data
                [parent_id] => 2
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [scheme_component_name] => test Data
        [parent_id] => 
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [scheme_component_name] => test Data
        [parent_id] => 
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [scheme_component_name] => test Data
        [parent_id] => 
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [scheme_component_name] => test Data
        [parent_id] => 
    )
```